# What is the best way to deal with online payments(mobile payments) in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay

Here is my question. I'm working on a app that customers can book flight tickets online. that means they can search for a flight, select it and book.

Now I'm stuck with the payment part( lots of confusions with this part because apple gets 30% for each purchase for digital goods).

but I think selling a tickets goes under service category. correct me if I'm wrong.

1. Should I use Apple Pay with this ? is this mandatory with after iOS 9 ? or can use 3rd party.
2. As I know , apple has mentioned that if we are selling physical goods or services we have to use a 3rd party payment process like Stipe.if we go in this method, do we have to pay 30% from each purchase.
3. In other hand, my clients asked me to implement the payment part with their existing web payment.is this a good idea and , is it that much easy to do this.

need your help and idea with this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to clear you that Apple Pay is available only for `US, UK, Canada, and Australia` on supported iOS devices. The Implementation of Apple pay is very easy follow my article -

[apple pay step by step implementation using braintree](https://anupammishra.wordpress.com/2016/06/10/apple-pay-step-by-step-implementation-using-braintree/)

Comment: I want to enable this to anyone

Comment: You can't please have a look Apple Pay developer guideline https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/

Comment: Can I do without apple pay, by using any third party payment gateways

Comment: yes you can use PayPal using braintree - https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/overview/ios/v4

Comment: do I have to use paypay, instead of that can I use payment gateway like stripe to deal with credit cards

Comment: Yes you can use Braintree for that.

Comment: You're mistaken: Apple Pay is available in China, US, UK, Canada, Australia, France, Hong Kong, and Singapore right now. There is no charge from Apple to use it - it costs whatever you usual payment processor (Stripe, Braintree, somebody else) would charge you to accept credit/debit cards.